# Intelliji IDE, проблема с отображением интерфейса среды

Tags: intellij-idea, java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникает проблема с отображением среды разработки Java, перепробовал уже все, что можно: шрифты, кодировки, сносил полностью JDK и ставил заново, ничего не помогает. Более того, установил еще Net Beans, там такая же ситуация.

Comment: А если щёлкнуть на + что нибудь меняется?

Comment: Вероятно, стоит обратиться в техподдержку JetBrains.